# How to add text to responsive background canvas to a webpage?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I want to create a Welcome Page with a responsive background like this fiddle 
https://codepen.io/JulianLaval/pen/KpLXOO/. 
I tried using

```
var ctx = canvasDiv.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
ctx.fillText("Hi", canvasDiv.width / 2, canvasDiv.height / 2);
```

But it is not working.
Any help?

Comment: As long as canvasDiv is an actual reference to a valid canvas this code should work. Maybe your font is just too small to see? Try: `ctx.font = "60px Arial";` before fillText()

Comment: Not working :( I think the 'var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);' line in the JS is the issue, fillText before this results in a Blank page

Comment: Is it important to have your text in the same canvas? If not just put it in a div or on another canvas on top, because the underlying canvas is constantly being rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can **not** simply reuse the canvas of the particle library - at least not without modifications to the particle library itself.

This library has it's own `update()` function which we can see at this github link: [ParticleNetwork.prototype.update](https://github.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/blob/master/particle-network.js#L208)

So initially it clears it's canvas, draws the particles and finally schedules a call to itself - so it constantly repaints the canvas with the displays refresh rate.
No here's the problem - if you simply draw something to it's canvas it will ultimately be overwritten by this update function.

If you want to draw text on it's canvas, you have to do it inside this function.

For example, find these lines of code:

```
  if (this.options.velocity !== 0) {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
```

if you add the following lines before:

```
this.ctx.fillStyle = "RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
this.ctx.fillText("Hi", this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2);
```

You will have your desired text.